# How can i get all child items (position wise) when clicked on Listview?

Tags: android, listview

Here is my MainActivity Listview listener,

```
                        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    DetailPackageVO pckg=expListAdapter.getItem(position);

                                    package_id=pckg.getId();    
                                    selectedPackageName=pckg.getBasic();
                                    itemTotalPrice=pckg.getTotal_amount();
                                    itemDiscount=pckg.getDiscount_percentage();
                                    itemAmountafterDiscount=pckg.getAmount_after_discount();

                                    System.out.println("::"+package_id+":"+selectedPackageName);

                            }
                        });
                    }
```

My DetailPackageVO  Class,

```
public class DetailPackageVO {


    String id,basic, total_amount,amount_after_discount,discount_percentage;


    private ArrayList<ServiceVo> children;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getBasic() {
        return basic;
    }

    public void setBasic(String basic) {
        this.basic = basic;
    }

    public String getTotal_amount() {
        return total_amount;
    }

    public void setTotal_amount(String total_amount) {
        this.total_amount = total_amount;
    }

    public String getAmount_after_discount() {
        return amount_after_discount;
    }

    public void setAmount_after_discount(String amount_after_discount) {
        this.amount_after_discount = amount_after_discount;
    }

    public String getDiscount_percentage() {
        return discount_percentage;
    }

    public void setDiscount_percentage(String discount_percentage) {
        this.discount_percentage = discount_percentage;
    }

    public ArrayList<ServiceVo> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(ArrayList<ServiceVo> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

How can i get all child items that i have saved in `ArrayList<ServiceVo>` in DetailPackageVO Class, when clicked on position of listview item.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: create `ServiceVo` object, fill it with value and add it to your arraylist...

Answer (score 0):

Declare a getter and setter for children property in DetailPackageVO, like you have declared for all other properties.

```
public void setChildren(ArrayList<ServiceVo> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
    public ArrayList<ServiceVo> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }
```

and in onItemClick you can access children using the getter you have declared :)

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            DetailPackageVO pckg=expListAdapter.getItem(position);

            package_id=pckg.getId();  selectedPackageName=pckg.getBasic();
            itemTotalPrice=pckg.getTotal_amount();
            itemDiscount=pckg.getDiscount_percentage();
            itemAmountafterDiscount=pckg.getAmount_after_discount();

            ArrayList<ServiceVo> childItems = pckg.getChildren();
            for ( ServiceVo child : childItems) {
                System.out.println(child.childspropertyhere);
            }
            System.out.println("::"+package_id+":"+selectedPackageName);

        }
    });
```